# Datagridview combo box , Check if value is already entered

Tags: c#, datagridview, combobox

I have a DGV datagridview2 of one column, which is of type combo box.
The combo box of the dgv has as a source a datatable called dt_2.
If i enter a value in the second row, i want to check if the value already exists in the first row, validation will not be allowed.

I have used the following code, but sometimes it's not allowing me to validate even if the value doesn't exist before

```
private void dataGridView2_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
 {
var dataGrid = sender as DataGridView;
 if (dataGrid == null) return;

var rowsWithComboValues = dataGrid.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Where(row => row.Cells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>().First().Value != null);
if (rowsWithComboValues.Any(row => string.Compare(row.Cells[0].Value.ToString(), e.FormattedValue.ToString(), true) == 0))
{
e.Cancel = true;
MessageBox.Show("Value already selected!");

}
}
```

Thank you

Comment: What do You mean by "not allowing me to validate" ?

Comment: @MajkeloDev not allowing me to pick a value and end edit